# Handle angular bracket in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

Currently when trying to submit transaction that contain dropdown that has text containg angular bracket as e.g. `"<abcd>"`, I'm getting 500 internal server error since `ValidateRequest=true` by default and throws unhandled exception before it reached to page handler since its Cross site scripting problem.

Is there a way to intercept and modify request object in `HttpModule` or `Glabal.asax` since I know Request object is readonly.

I've been breaking head for almost three days but not able to get a concrete solution.
What would be the best solution to handle these kind of scenarios. Also I don't want to encode it in client side.

Comment: how do you populate the listbox ?

Comment: Its a drop down and not listbox. I'm binding dropdown to the datatable. DataTablew containd data whose text might have <abc> as values.

Comment: show us the definition of the datasource and the dropdown... standard databinding **does** html encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use [Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library V4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5242) as it provides many helper functions to encode HTML, HtmlAttribute, JavaScript, URL, XML to restrict any cross site attacks.

Answer (score 3):

<s>Encode the value in the listbox :</s>

```
<asp:ListItem>&lt;abcd&gt;</asp:ListItem>
```

**[Edit]** I realize my solution does not apply. The content is probably sent encoded by the browser, and is render encoded too by the drop down list (if you use standard databinding). I think your only option is to disable the validation of the request.

This implies you have to very careful on user input. To be simple, Encode every user input with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtXX.Text);`.

More on this in the [Script Exploits Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx) page of MSDN.

Comment: But it will look very much messy for end user having those characters (i.e &lt; or &gt;) visible in UI. I would like to handle "<abc>" on postback while clicking on submit button.

Comment: it will be decoded by the browser. It's the standard way to represent characters used by html syntax : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2

Comment: I do not want to set ValidateRequest to false instead am looking for a universal solution wherein i can handle request and modify. Probably am not hitting on right track. I tried with HttpModule but I got failed in modifying request object.

Comment: Why don't you want to set ValidateRequest to false ? If use with precaution, it will be far more simple than hooking the request to patch data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx)  and [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) to solve this problem..

you can put html encoded text in the control or use these methods as per your requirement( Between Events)

Follow these SO thread...
[HttpUtility.HtmlEncode to validate user entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806834/httputility-htmlencode-to-validate-user-entries)
[w3c validation error in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689804/w3c-validation-error-in-asp-net)

If you can disable validation then follow these
[asp.net: Invalid postback or callback argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476329/asp-net-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument)

Check MSDN for [Script Exploits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx)